# Need to open ports for scanner 18.04

Tags: networking, iptables, firewall, scanner

I have Ubuntu 18.04 desktop standard install on my laptop.
My scanner needs a couple of ports open for the scan key on it.
How do I open ports, should I install UFW and use that?
Scanner works ok with scanner application on pc but will not accept connection when initiated from scanner.
Need:
Inbound direction : UDP Port 54925
Outbound direction : TCP Port 54921
Thanks

Comment: Hello, I would recommend you to start with `ufw` and its GUI `gufw`. This is pretty enough for this task and it is easy to be done. Keep in your mind if you are behind NAT, router you will need to do some port forwarding via its interface. ... hmm, I think Ubuntu Desktop comes without any firewall restrictions by default, so probably you just need to do port forwarding.

Comment: By default nothing is blocked. Tell us what you are currently already running that might be blocking those ports.